# print Sprintf error while the input is a string which consist of symbol in heatmap gnuplot

Tags: awk, graph, printf, gnuplot, heatmap

I am working on heat map with a unique dataset. The dataset consists of a symbol. 
Here is the example of  my dataset 1q.txt

```
            one         two         three   
2009        0/0    1    0/0    1    0/0      1      
2010        0/0    1    0/0    1    0/0      1      
2011        0/0    1    0/0    1    6/179.5  1  
2012        0/0    1    2/0.4  1    11/83.0  1
2013        7/0.8  1    7/21.3 1    17/268.5 1
2014        1/3.5  1    4/7.7  1    9/37.9   1
```

and here is my gnuplot script

```
set term pos eps font 20
unset colorbox
unset key
set nocbtics
set cblabel "Score" 
set cbtics scale 0
set cbrange [ 0.00000 : 110.00000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set palette defined ( 0.0 "#FFFFFF",\
                      1 "#FFCCCC",\
                      2 "#FF9999 ",\
                      3 "#FF6666")

set size 1, 0.5
set output '1q.eps'
YTICS="`awk 'BEGIN{getline}{printf "%s ",$1}' '1q.dat'`"
XTICS="`head -1 '1q.dat'`"
set for [i=1:words(XTICS)] xtics ( word(XTICS,i) i-1 )
set for [i=1:words(YTICS)] ytics ( word(YTICS,i) i-1 )

set for [i=1:words(XTICS)] xtics ( word(XTICS,i) 2*i-1 )
plot "<awk '{$1=\"\"}1' '1q.dat' | sed '1 d'" matrix every 2::1 w image, \
     '' matrix using ($1+1):2:(sprintf('%.f', $3)) every 2 with labels
```

What I'm trying to do here is I want to displaying "0/0" as a label in the heatmap and the integer number as a heatmap color.

The problem that I face here is the gnuplot only take a number before "/"
 and ignore the other one.

Here is the result of my current plot.

[image]

How to make the heatmap show a lable like "1/3.5" and have color based on the integer number.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use`sprintf` at all. Simply use `stringcolumn` to get the raw content of a column as saved in the data file:

```
plot "<awk '{$1=\"\"}1' '1q.dat' | sed '1 d'" matrix every 2::1 w image, \
 '' matrix using ($1+1):2:(stringcolumn(3)) every 2 with labels
```

Comment: Hi @Christoph, When change it to stringcolumn.. I found an error ` stringcolumn() called from invalid context`.. the error pointing 'with labels' at the second line in the last code. do you know what is that mean?

Comment: Seems like `stringcolumn` doesn't work together with `matrix`, sorry

Comment: thank you for the information. so that the only way to solve this is use sprinf?

Comment: No, because `sprintf` only comes later, you still need a way to get the string content of a column. You would need to change your data file, but in that case you must change the way the ytics and xtics are saved.

Comment: alright, I am just revisiting http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html ... I will try to update the ytics and xtics.. probably I can use awk and seed to get the string content.. but still not sure how to show it inside the heatmap