# Using sprintf to print string value

Tags: printf, gnuplot

Actually, I get this problem in Gnuplot. But in a simple way, the problem is I want to use sprintf to print in string format, even though the string consists of numbers and symbol. Like this:

```
a = '12/7'

sprintf('%.f', a)
```

I am able to run it in Gnuplot, but it only shows numbers before symbol "/". I expect the output should print all the content of variable `a` which is '12/7'. Any suggestion for this case?

Answer (score 9):

If you are referring to the `sprintf` built-in function in `gnuplot`, the documentation `help sprintf` says:

> `sprintf("format",var1,var2,...)` applies standard C-language format
>   specifiers  to multiple arguments and returns the resulting string. If
>   you want to  use gnuplot's own format specifiers, you must instead
>   call `gprintf()`.  For information on sprintf format specifiers,
>   please see standard C-language  documentation or the unix sprintf man
>   page.

In the Unix man page for `%f` says (truncated):

> %f, %F  -- The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal
>   notation
>                 in  the  style  [-]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits after the
>                 decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification.

Hence, you need to use a different format specifier. As fedorqui pointed out the appropriate format specifier is `%s`.

I often refer to [the table in this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for looking up the appropriate format specifiers (I find the C man page a bit long).

**Using `sprintf` with strings from files**

In order to use `sprintf` to format a string from a file, you need to specify the column in the file to extract the string information from.  This needs to be done using the `stringcolumn` command instead of just using a `$` sign.

For example, if you wanted to include a number from a file you might use a command like:

```
plot "data.dat" using 1:2:(sprintf('%f', $3)) with labels
```

But for a string you need:

```
plot "data.dat" using 1:2:(sprintf('%s', stringcolumn(3))) with labels
```

Comment: thanks you for the answer @ilent2, I have tried `%s` but it shows an error `f_sprintf: attempt to print numeric value with string format` do you have any idea for that?

Comment: @indi60 Are you sure the variable is a string?  When I run gnuplot with `gnuplot> a = '3.5'` and `gnuplot> print(sprintf('%s hi', a))` it works fine for me.  Could you edit your original question with the exact code your using.

Comment: here is my plot file `plot "<awk '{$1=\"\"}1' '1q.dat' | sed '1 d'" matrix every 2::1 w image, \
     '' matrix using ($1+1):2:(sprintf('%.f', $3)) every 2 with labels`

Comment: actually you can see my input and whole plot file in this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504450/print-sprintf-error-while-the-input-is-a-string-which-consist-of-symbol-in-heatm

Comment: @indi60 So, to fix your plot command try: `plot "<awk '{$1=\"\"}1' '1q.dat' | sed '1 d'" matrix every 2::1 w image, \ '' matrix using ($1+1):2:(sprintf('%s', stringcolumn(3))) every 2 with labels`.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: it still doesn't work... the error is `stringcolumn() called from invalid context` . @Christoph said that stringcolumn() doesn't work in matrix. BTW, nice try...

Answer (score 3):

When you say

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {a="12/7"; printf "%.f", a}'
12
```

You get the int part of the number, because by using a `f` flag in [printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers) you are casting it to a number instead of a string. So it is equivalent to saying:

```
awk 'BEGIN {a="12/7"; a=int(a); print a}'
```

If you want to keep all of it, use `%s` for string:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%s", "234-456"}'
234-456
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply by floating-point number and use that as following: 
`sprintf('%.f', a*1.0)`

In this way, you force **gnuplot** to treat **a** as floating-point number.